# Entity field type with identity through foreign entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a `Profile` entity with simple derived identity taken from a `User` entity, as explained in [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity). So the `User` provides the `id` and the `Profile` uses the foreign key as identifier.

```
User:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO

Profile:
  type: entity
  id:
    user:
      associationKey: true
  oneToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
```

Then I have an entity field within a form, using `Profile` as class.

```
->add('profile', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Profile'
))
```

I expected the resulting element to be, as usual, something like:

```
<select>
    <option value="[id of the profile]">[toString of the profile]</option>
</select>
```

But instead I get:

```
<select>
    <option value="[toString of the user]">[toString of the profile]</option>
</select>
```

Of course, when submitting the form I get a validation error because it expects an `id` but gets an string.

How could I force the field to use the profile `id` as `value`? Or at least the user `id` (that is the same).

Answer (score 0):

Use the "property". http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property

You 'll see answer in manual

Comment: `property` changes the text part of the `<option>` element, not the `value`

Comment: Maybe You have to use transform in this case

Comment: Maybe, but I can not figure out how